# JmsPoolConnectionFactory uses wrong keystore during sslEnabled connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis, spring-3

When I'm using `org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory with org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and `sslEnabled=true` I'm getting an error when receiving message from connected queue about unknown keystore even though I've specified keyStorePath and keyStorePassword in my brokerUrl connection string.

```
13:27:28.577 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] WARN  i.n.c.ChannelInitializer - Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xa7f380fc]
java.lang.Exception: Failed to find a store at /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/keystore.jks
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.validateStoreURL(SSLSupport.java:399)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeystore(SSLSupport.java:339)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeyManagerFactory(SSLSupport.java:375)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeyManagers(SSLSupport.java:355)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.createContext(SSLSupport.java:222)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.DefaultSSLContextFactory.getSSLContext(DefaultSSLContextFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.loadJdkSslEngine(NettyConnector.java:786)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$1.initChannel(NettyConnector.java:690)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1114)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1115)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
13:27:28.583 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[T24.MCZAKOQUEUE.UAT]] ERROR o.a.a.a.c.client - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)
13:27:28.591 [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] WARN  i.n.c.ChannelInitializer - Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x70b07b6d]
java.lang.Exception: Failed to find a store at /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/keystore.jks
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.validateStoreURL(SSLSupport.java:399)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeystore(SSLSupport.java:339)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeyManagerFactory(SSLSupport.java:375)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeyManagers(SSLSupport.java:355)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.createContext(SSLSupport.java:222)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.DefaultSSLContextFactory.getSSLContext(DefaultSSLContextFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.loadJdkSslEngine(NettyConnector.java:786)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$1.initChannel(NettyConnector.java:690)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1114)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1115)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
13:27:28.591 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[T24.MCZAKOQUEUE.UAT]] ERROR o.a.a.a.c.client - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
```

The path to the keystore mentioned in the stack trace is actually defined in the brokers acceptor so I believe that the connection factory for some reason first tries to create a connection to queue using the keystore specified inside the broker and after this fails it connects with the keystore I've specified in my connection string. After this the message is consumed and processed.

SpringBoot version: 3.1.2
Apache camel version 4.0.0

ApplicationConfig.java

```
import jakarta.jms.JMSException;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * XML free configuration of the base component scan.
 *
 * <p>It registers all application components.
 *
 * @author here comes a real name
 */
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean(name = "artemis")
    public JmsComponent managedArtemis() throws JMSException {
        JmsPoolConnectionFactory jmsPoolConnectionFactory = getJmsPoolConnectionFactory();

        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(jmsPoolConnectionFactory);
        jmsConfiguration.setArtemisStreamingEnabled(true);
        jmsConfiguration.setAcknowledgementModeName("CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE");
        jmsConfiguration.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(50);
        jmsConfiguration.setMaxMessagesPerTask(100);
        
        JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);

        return jmsComponent;
    }

    @NotNull
    private static JmsPoolConnectionFactory getJmsPoolConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://<broker-host>:61616?ha=true&sslEnabled=true&keyStorePath=<path-to-key-store>&keyStorePassword=password&trustStorePath=<path-to-trust-store>&trustStorePassword=password");

        JmsPoolConnectionFactory jmsPoolConnectionFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
        jmsPoolConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        jmsPoolConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(100);
        return jmsPoolConnectionFactory;
    }

}
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jakarta-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
            <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `broker.xml` as well?

Comment: JMS Pool is just a thin wrapper around a JMS connection factory and knows nothing about implementations so the issue isn't in the pool.  You need to provide all configuration you are using an ensure you are actually using what you think you are.